# Changing URL using WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium WebDriver (Java) and am trying to change the URL after WebDriver has logged into a page.

Is there a way to either:

1. Change the URL of the current window, or
2. Open a new tab and go to another page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You didn't share any code so i don't know how is your approach about it, I only share my knowledge about this subject.

**1)** For your first question i think you know how to open a new page with selenium web driver maybe you can use some wait method and then invoke the driver again.

```
    //open browser
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //login
    driver.get("https://www.google.com/");

    //set implicit wait
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    //Then invoke method again for your second request(I am not try this code maybe you need to create new driver object)
    driver.get("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

**2)** For your second question this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358316/selenium-web-driver-open-new-tab-instead-of-a-new-window) help you.

Comment: Hmm... it must be something w/ the site that I'm testing because I can't seem to open the second link using `driver.get()` but if I try your example, it works.

Comment: Actually, it looks like for my situation, I _did_ need to create a new WebDriver instance.