# Selenium IDE for Firefox Ctrl-Tab

Tags: firefox, selenium, ide, selenium-ide

I'm attempting to automate some settings in multiple forms from a list that I open  into their own tabs. 
The easiest way that I can prep the pages prior to running the script is to have them all open .
I intend to have selenium run through the changes to the form, then I want it to **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>** to the next one. I will use a loop while to set the count.
I currently have it recording in HTML, if I need to adjust it over to java or I will gladly do so.

I've attempted to record it, but no go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no support for tabs in Selenium as of now. [A fairly recent answer by one of the Selenium developers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11358741/1273080) explains it pretty clearly:

> Selenium has no ability to switch tabs at the moment. Because of this
>   we force the browser to open links in new windows but since we are
>   able to switch windows we force the browser to take the approach. This
>   **may** be fixed in a later version.

Also, if you get away from IDE (or export your testcase to WebDriver) and get to a more powerful tool (any full-strength programming language binding for Selenium), you might use some kind of workaround:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12730918/1273080 (Taps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> to get to the second tab etc.) However, this kind of workarounds is usually limited to a certain browser/OS/browser setting (tabs can be disabled).

---

That said, if you don't insist on using tabs and would use several browser windows instead, that's fairly easy in IDE as well as Selenium RC and WebDriver:

Selenium IDE: [`selectWindow`](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#selectWindow) (you can spawn a new window by [openWindow](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0/reference.html#openWindow))

Selenium RC: [`selectWindow()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Selenium.html#selectWindow%28java.lang.String%29)

Selenium WebDriver: [`switchTo().window()`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#window%28java.lang.String%29)