# Switch tabs with Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, selenium-ide

I'm new to Selenium IDE.We are testing a site using IDE where we register at the front-end as a new customer and then open the back-end in another tab and check if the customer is registered or not.My problem is I can't switch between tabs using IDE.I tried using "Select Window" but nothing worked.Please give me an example code if possible.

Comment: I think it's possible.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550360/selenium-ide-for-firefox-ctrl-tab

Comment: Thanks Lima,I also used the same method to solve the problem.