# open a browser tab using Ruby selenium

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Can someone help me with what is wrong with the below code. My intention is to be able to open a new tab in the browser. The script passes, but doesn't really open a new tab

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

@browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
@browser.navigate.to "http://www.google.com"
body = @browser.find_element(:tag_name => 'body')
body.send_keys(:control, 't')

p "total number of windows"
p @browser.window_handles.length
p "printing window ids"
@browser.window_handles.each do  |window|
  p  window
end
@browser.quit
```

Comment: did you find any of the answers useful?

Comment: Actually none of the below answers opened a new tab. Sorry for the delay in reply.

Comment: So after reading more on opening new tab vs. new window (across all browsers), seems like it is more of a user preference setting. So if I would like to open a new tab, I should create an <a> which does NOT have width, height attributes specified. If those attributes are specified, clicking that link would open a new window - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726761/javascript-open-in-a-new-window-not-tab . Seemed way too much work to do just to open a new tab and there is no universal agreement on how to open a new tab vs. window through script

Answer (score 5):

The closest I've got to opening and managing a new tab using Chrome is:

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome
driver.get 'http://www.google.com'

#Extract the link we want to go to
address = driver.find_element(:link_text, "Gmail").attribute('href')

#Open a new browser window
driver.execute_script( "window.open()" )

#Use the newest window
driver.switch_to.window( driver.window_handles.last )
driver.get 'http://yahoo.com'
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps, however I could as well create a new webdriver instance and use that. I really want to do the exact operations of ctrl+t which opens a new tab in chrome browser through code. Any more thoughts ?

Comment: It's a Selenium issue, it doesn't support opening new tabs, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550360/selenium-ide-for-firefox-ctrl-tab/14552367#14552367

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Mac, try:

```
body.send_keys(:command, 't')
```

instead of

```
body.send_keys(:control, 't')
```

Look here too: [How to open a new tab using Selenium WebDriver with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547473/how-to-open-a-new-tab-using-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I already looked into this link you shared and that is when I posted this question because the behavior is NOT seen in terms of opening a new tab. I am on windows btw. Any more ideas ?