# How to open new tab in IE using selenium (java) and open a url in that tab (not window)

Tags: java, selenium, tabs

How do I open a new tab in IE using selenium (java) and open a url in that tab (not window)?
I am using the below code to open a new tab?

```
driver.get("https://google.com/");

//below line of code opens a new tab but does sets control on new tab.
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");//opens new tab

// As control does not sets on new tab, the below link opens on first tab only..
driver.get("https://facebook.com/");//but load facebook in first tab i.e on google page
```

Can anyone tell me, how to shift control to new tab so that the facebook link opens in that new tab.

Hi

I using Selenium Web-Driver Version 2.40 and IE 11.0

```
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(ieCapabilities);

driver.manage().window().maximize();

  driver.get("https://google.com/");

  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("Body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");//opens new tab

 //Store the current window handle

  String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

  //Perform the click operation that opens new window //Switch to new window open 

   for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){

   driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

    driver.get("https://facebook.com/");

    }

    // Perform the actions on new window

    //Close the new window, if that window no more required

   driver.close();

   //Switch back to original browser (first window)

     driver.switchTo().window(winHandleBefore);

     //continue with original browser (first window)
```

I am not able to open facebook on new tab of same window..

Regards
Shashank Goyal

Comment: This link explains in detail how to go about switching windows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9588827/webdriver-switch-to-new-browser-opened-after-click-on-button

Comment: I am asking to work on new tab , not on new window.

Comment: A tab is considered a new window by Selenium.

Comment: Note: AFAIK, Selenium [doesnot open new tabs, only new windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358316/selenium-web-driver-open-new-tab-instead-of-a-new-window/11358741#11358741). Your workaround will work I believe, however selenium will still treat it as a new window and you can switch to it using `driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle)`

Comment: I am using selenium 2.40 and IE 11.0 and i am not able to open link in  new tab of same window.I have provided the code above,that i am using.Can you please provide the code in java,so that i can go through this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use

```
driver.switchTo().window(String)
```

to switch to the window that has come up just as you would with opening a new window.

Comment: Is there any difference between a window and a new tab?Here i am asking for new tab , not new window

Comment: no difference, nope. it'll still be considered a "window handle", therefore they aren't exclusive.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> tabHandles1 = new ArrayList<String>(driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().window(tabHandles1.get(index));
```

u can pass the place the value of index or can iterate to all the tab using arrayList tabhandles1