# Open hyperlink in the same window, different tab

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

I used the below code options to open a hyperlink in the same window and a different tab, but every time the link will open in a different window.

**1)**

```
String selectLinkOpeninNewTab = Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.RETURN);   
driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText)).sendKeys(selectLinkOpeninNewTab);
```

**2)**

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);  
act.moveToElement(element).doubleClick(element))).build().perform();
```

**3)**

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
act.contextClick(driver.findElement(By.xpath(element)))
    .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    .sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN)
    .sendKeys(Keys.RETURN)
    .build()
    .perform();
```

Expecting link should be open in the same window different tab, but every time it is opening in the new window.

Please help.

Comment: You can try to refer this link may help to solve your issue. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22820527/how-to-open-new-tab-in-ie-using-selenium-java-and-open-a-url-in-that-tab-not

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this approach as keyboard manipulation is definitely not something you want as it will be the major constraint violating [Parallel Testing Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices), to wit you will not be able to run your tests in [Selenium Grid](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/07_selenium_grid.jsp)

I would suggest going for an alternative approach to wit:

1. Extract [`href` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_href.asp) from the link
2. Open a new tab using [Window.open()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function via [`driver.executeScript()` function](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html#executeScript-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object...-)
3. Switch to the new tab using [driver.switchTo().window()](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.TargetLocator.html#window-java.lang.String-) function

Example code:

```
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.linkText(linkText));
String href = link.getAttribute("href");
driver.executeScript("window.open('" + href + "');");
driver.switchTo().window(driver.getWindowHandles().stream().reduce((f, s) -> s).orElse(null));
System.out.println(driver.getTitle()); // at this point you should see the new page title
```