# How to switch between 2 different tabs of browser in Selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to switch between 2 tabs of browser. Currently tried of getting number of window handles, but even though 2 tabs are open its shows as 1.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SO Ques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28165193/opening-a-new-tab-in-the-same-window-session-of-the-browser-through-selenium-web)

Comment: @VivekSingh - I do not think it is duplicate. can you please re check? Link which you have shared has answer to open link in new tab.

Comment: @Suyog - Please refer this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11358316/selenium-web-driver-open-new-tab-instead-of-a-new-window/11358741#11358741

Answer (score 1):

You never mentioned any `language` you are using. But, I use the following to handle some of my tests

```
Driver.SwitchTo().Window(Driver.WindowHandles.LastOrDefault());
```

Mine is C# but it would be pretty simple to convert.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can get windowhandles of those tabs whose origin is same....
if the web application origin is different then you'll not get window handle

If its from same origin then this issue may come in Internet Explorer 9-
I have come across this issue before in IE Browser..

You may also want to refer your company's security policy .. maybe it can be the cause to detach second window from the parent window....